# How to enable bundling and minification on IIS 6 and Asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, iis, optimization, web-config

I am trying to publish my website to deployment server.which includes changes to global.asax file's application_start.it calls method which reads one xml and registers a bundle to compress js/css files.It works fine with local solution and in IIS 7 Web server version.

But when I deploy same application to server in IIS 6 bundled resources are not loading to the page and i am not load the js/css from URL.I suspect problem with global.asax as this file makes a call to the bundle class to register bundled resources.but not sure.

When i look at the global.asax file.Global.asax file is present in root directory of published folder.and global dll files are present in bin folder too.

I don't understand the reason why its not updating the global.asax file in  server with IIS 6 or any problem with IIS 6 Configuration.

Due this issue i am not able deploy it to server.

If any configuration settings in IIS 6 is required  to solve this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Build action of the `Global.asax` file is set to `Content` in the file properties.
To deploy a file, it needs to be of type content.
You can access this by going to the properties of the file and making the change.

Comment: .It works fine with IIS7 but when i deploy to IIS 6 It does not work.